# Why is Train Heartnet called Black Cat?

Tags: black-cat

The main character of Black Cat, Train Heartnet, is called Black Cat. Where did that name come from? Is it a reference to him being an assassin and, as such, being "bad luck" for people whose paths he crosses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He called himself Black Cat because he brings misfortune. He also said to his victims *I have come to deliver some bad luck* before he kills them.

The motive of the bad luck also is shown in his number (13) and his birthday (13.4.; 13 => number of bad luck in western countries, while the four is the number for bad luck in Japan). Also his name has 13 characters.

Answer (score 3):

According [here](http://blackcat.wikia.com/wiki/Train_Heartnet),

> **Train's underground name is "Black Cat" because of the misfortune that lies in his wake.** He always says to his target "I have come to deliver some bad luck" before killing them and he always completes a mission with 100% accuracy, without remorse.